# Index hint with mongodb csharp

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am migrating from the mongodb csharp driver 1.10.0 to 2.0.0.
One of the collection I am using is very big and has to fulfill many queries with different filter attributes. That is why I was relying on some index hint statements. With the v1.10 driver it looks like

```
 myCollection.Find(query).SetHint("myIndexName");
```

I searched the v2 driver api but this hint method seems to be completly removed in the v2 driver. Is there an alternative? How should I do index hints with the v2 driver?

**Note:** The Solutions provided works for latest mongodb csharp drivers as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the FindOptions.Modifiers property.

```
var modifiers = new BsonDocument("$hint", "myIndexName"); 
await myCollection.Find(query, new FindOptions { Modifiers = modifiers }).ToListAsync();
```

May I ask why you are using the hint? Was the server consistently choosing the wrong index? You shouldn't need to do this except in exceptional cases.

Craig

Comment: thank you! this worked. yes, we were experiencing that the execution plan was not optimal (can't remember if consistently or only sometimes) that led to a bad response time. we also had a mongodb consultant here. (mongodb 2.6 on windows)

Comment: For me, MongoDB 3.2 doesn't select the correct index when sorting on a field. There basically only is one specialized index, but `explain` doesn't even mention it. Hinting does the trick.

Comment: Upvoted, but just be really careful with this. Mongo is usually pretty intelligent in which index it uses

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, try to make the query in a way that mongodb optimizer can use the index automatically.

If you are using `FindAsync` then you will have a property named `Hint`. Use it like this:

If you have index named "myIndexName" which you want your query should use forcefully, then use like this:.

```
BsonString bsonString = new BsonString("myIndexName");

cursor = await collection.FindAsync(y => y.Population > 400000000,
new FindOptions<Person, Person>()
{
     BatchSize = 200,
     NoCursorTimeout = true,
     AllowPartialResults = true,
     Projection = "{'_id':1,'Name':1,'Population':1}"
     Hint = bsonString.AsBsonValue,
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

You can fine `BsonString` class in `MongoDB.Bson`

Answer (score 1):

With agregate you can force indice like this:

```
BsonString bsonString = new BsonString("ix_indice");

var query = this.collection.Aggregate(new AggregateOptions() { Hint = bsonString }).Match(new BsonDocument {..});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Linq IQueryable, you can specify the hint (and other options) like this:

```cs
BsonDocument hint = new BsonDocument("myFieldName", 1);
// or
BsonDocument hint = new BsonString("myIndexName");

await collection.AsQueryable(new AggregateOptions { Hint = hint })
```

`myFieldName` can also reference a complex field, e.g. `Metadata.FileName`

`myIndexName` is the name of an index. I prefer to reference the field (first option) directly, instead of an index, for simple cases.